# Doing two things with output from a command

Tags: shell, text-processing, utilities

I have a program `texcount` that outputs the number of words in my LaTeX document. I can also pipe the output of this to `sed` to make the newlines TeX linebreaks and write this to a file which I can then include in my final document. But when I do `texcount foo.tex | sed s/$/'\\\\'/ > wc.tex` the command line output of `texcount` is suppressed.

How can I get the output of the first command to be displayed in the terminal *and* piped to sed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a anonymous pipe for the second command:

```
texcount foo.tex | tee >(sed s/$/'\\\\'/ > wc.tex)
```

Comment: The essential part of this answer is to use `tee`. If you're certain shells like Bash, you can pipe tee's output using `>(some further commands)`. In other shells, you'd have to give tee a filename argument (this is its standard mode of operation), and then run `some further commands < thatfile`, and then delete the thatfile. Or see Hari's answer below.

Comment: tee , tee & tee.

Answer (score 7):

You need the "tee" command, which allows you to split pipes.

```
texcount foo.tex | tee >output.txt | sed s/$/'\\\\'/ > wc.tex ; cat output.txt
```

This would leave you the additional output.txt file.
Read this for more info: http://www.unixtutorial.org/2007/12/tee-replicate-standard-output/ 
You can also do "man tee".

Comment: `texcount foo.tex | tee unmodified |sed s/$/'\\\\'/ > modified` puts modified and unmodified versions of the output in the two files. How do I print the unmodified version to the terminal? I tried `tee stdout` but that prints nothing...

Comment: You can't do that, because tee sends its input to stdout and a file.  The stdout is what becomes the input to sed.  You could add `&& cat unmodified` at the end.  That will dump the unmodifed output to the terminal.

Comment: The proper command line here would be `texcount foo.tex | tee output.txt | sed s/$/'\\\\'/ > wc.tex ; cat output.txt`. Or you could use `texcount foo.tex | tee output.txt; sed s/$/'\\\\'/ output.txt > wc.tex`. In either case, you'd then probably want to `rm output.txt` afterwards.

Comment: @dubiousjim That semicolon is correct - the pipe works, but the semi colon better expresses what is intended.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the fairly idiomatic

```
texcount foo.tex | tee /dev/tty | sed s/$/'\\\\'/ > wc.tex
```

`/dev/tty` is a magic device that refers to the controlling terminal of the current process.