# Splitting stdin to different outputs in bash

Tags: bash, io-redirection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way in bash to redirect output and still have it go to stdout?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4195/is-there-a-way-in-bash-to-redirect-output-and-still-have-it-go-to-stdout)

How would I send `/dev/stdin` to both `/dev/stdout` and a `$logfile` in one command?

One solution would be just to do it once for both:

```
 cat /dev/stdin > $tempfile;
 cat $tempfile > /dev/stdout;
 cat $tempfile > $logfile;
```

But that seems bad. Is there a better way?

Comment: I remember this question being ask before.

Comment: [This](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4195/250) is a duplicate. [This](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5677/250) is related.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command `tee` is exactly doing this :

```
cat /dev/stdin | tee $logfile
```